# How paste string from buffer to console program?

Tags: c++, windows, buffer

For example my Windows console program compute something and then says "Hey, user, copy url from you browser and paste it in program". Then user copies that url (e.g. google.com) and then what I should use in order user just simply pasted it to console window.

Comment: cin will work with this for windows or linux with no special handling provided the user understands how to paste into a cmd.exe or a terminal.

Comment: with cin i can only type string, but not paste it from buffer

Comment: `cin` has nothing to do with it. You probably need to look at the documentation for your console (I think you have to right click and select `paste`).

Comment: Did you right click on the command window and use the paste from the popup menu?

Comment: rigth click on command window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click the title bar of the Console Window, select Edit -> Paste. Cin should be able to read the text just fine.

Comment: (And hit return probably)

Comment: How I can do the same, but by right clicking on console window like in cmd.exe?

Comment: @Sunrise your last question makes no sense to me. Right clicking on a cmd.exe window or console window or console based application should all work the same way.

Comment: @drescherjm In all my console applications I can't just do right click in black area of console window and then paste, but in cmd I can

Comment: I have not seen that behavior. Although I launch most of my console programs inside of a cmd.exe.

Comment: When I execute my program through cmd.exe then it works.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39510/discussion-between-sunrise-and-drescherjm)

Answer (score 1):

I often use this one (slightly geeky):
ALT + Space
Then E
Then P